# Calling Php Strings from array

Tags: php, arrays, function

Hi I'm using this plugin called Meta Slider light and what I am trying to accomplish is getting the `<li>` to call the class of the image id.

Each Image has an ID and It calls the ID in the Img class but I want it to call it in the `<li>` class.

Below is the source code.

https://github.com/mihadaiko/ml-slider/blob/master/inc/slide/metaslide.image.class.php

on line 215 this code

`'class' => "slider-{$this->slider->ID} slide-{$this->slide->ID}",`

that code gives me this --> `<img src="img url" class="slider-ID slide-ID">`

The class calls for the Slider ID and The slide id.

and on line 347 it calls the `<li>` element.

`$html = '<li style="display: none;"' . $thumb . '>' . $html . '</li>';`

Each image is wrappen in an `<li>` element.

which gives me this

`<li style="display:none;"><img src="img url"> class="slider-ID slide-ID"></li>`

What I want to do is add the class line to the `<li>` element.

So far I have tried this

`$html = '<li style="display: none;" class="slide-{$this->slide->ID}" ' . $thumb . '>' . $html . '</li>';`

and it is still not working, it's calling the actual code instead of the image id. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The value in there is most likely escaped before being printed. This means that your PHP is never given the chance to evaluate before being output on the page. I could be wrong, but it looks that way.

Try this instead

```
'class' => "slider-" . $this->slider->ID . " slide-" . $this->slide->ID,
```

edit, this

```
$html = '<li style="display: none;" class="slide-'. $this->slide->ID .'" ' . $thumb . '>' . $html . '</li>';
```

Comment: Do i put that in the class object here `<li style="display:none; class="code here"></li>` @castis

Comment: you can also use sprintf to format your output as follow: `'class' => sprintf("slider-%d slide-%d", $this->slider->ID, $this->slide->ID);`

Comment: check my revised question :) @Castis

Comment: i revised my question @Aif